# How to compare Integer type record with String Type Record in MS_Access?

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I have two tables in my DB.
Table `Other` Has `RMA_no` as `'Number'`
& table `Material_Require_Master` Has `RMA_No` as `TEXT`.

I want to perform a query that can output tuples that have matching `RMA_No`?

So far I have done this.

```
String sql="Select RMA_Master.RMA_No,Call_Date,Source,Item_name,
                   Booking_Desc,Customer_name,Customer_contact,
                   AssignedTo,Part_No,Part_Name,Part_Quantity,
                   Part_Price,Total 
            From RMA_Master,Material_Require_Master 
            WHERE RMA_Master.RMA_No=Material_Require_Master.RMA_No AND
                  RMA_Master.MaterialRequireStatus='"+materialStatus+"' 
            UNION 
            Select Other.RMA_No,Call_Date,Source,Item_name,
                   Booking_Desc,Customer_name,Customer_contact,
                   AssignedTo,Part_No,Part_Name,Part_Quantity,
                   Part_Price,Total 
            From Other,Material_Require_Master 
            WHERE String.valueOf(Other.RMA_No)= Material_Require_Master.RMA_No AND
                  Other.MaterialRequireStatus='"+materialStatus+"'";

PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();    
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));          
rs.close();
pst.close();
```

And my StackTrace is :

```
Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function 'String.valueOf' in expression.
```

Also When I don't use `String.valueOf`:

```
String sql="Select RMA_Master.RMA_No,Call_Date,Source,Item_name,Booking_Desc,Customer_name,Customer_contact,AssignedTo,Part_No,Part_Name,Part_Quantity,Part_Price,Total From RMA_Master,Material_Require_Master WHERE RMA_Master.RMA_No=Material_Require_Master.RMA_No AND RMA_Master.MaterialRequireStatus='"+materialStatus+"' UNION Select Other.RMA_No,Call_Date,Source,Item_name,Booking_Desc,Customer_name,Customer_contact,AssignedTo,Part_No,Part_Name,Part_Quantity,Part_Price,Total From Other,Material_Require_Master WHERE Other.RMA_No= Material_Require_Master.RMA_No AND Other.MaterialRequireStatus='"+materialStatus+"'";
```

Following `Exception` occurs:

```
Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Type mismatch in expression.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you messed up between SQL and Java. 
`String.valueOf()` is a Java method you can't use in your SQL statement. There is `STR()` in SQL that you can use to convert a number into a string. Use it in conjonction with `LTRIM()` in order to remove whitespace padding, e.g. `LTRIM(STR(Other.RMA_no))`.

But anyway, the other way around is better as proposed by @Gord.

Answer (score 0):

With two test tables

[Material_Require_Master]
RMA_No - Text
mrmText - Text

[Other]
RMA_no - Number (Long Integer)
otherText - Text

The following query ...

```sql
SELECT Other.RMA_no, Other.otherText, Material_Require_Master.mrmText
FROM Material_Require_Master INNER JOIN Other 
    ON Material_Require_Master.RMA_No = Other.RMA_no;
```

... does indeed produce the error

> Type mismatch in expression.

If we add the `CLng()` function to the ON clause of the join to convert Material_Require_Master.RMA_No from text to a long integer ...

```sql
SELECT Other.RMA_no, Other.otherText, Material_Require_Master.mrmText
FROM Material_Require_Master INNER JOIN Other 
    ON CLng(Material_Require_Master.RMA_No) = Other.RMA_no;
```

... then the query runs without error.

Comment: No Success.. Its Producing the Same Error.

Comment: I Have Used : SELECT Other.RMA_No,Material_Require_Master.VAT FROM Material_Require_Master INNER JOIN Other ON CLng(Material_Require_Master.RMA_No) = Other.RMA_No

Comment: ... and that gives you the "Type mismatch in expression." error, too? If so, try applying `CLng()` to Other.RMA_No as well and see if that helps.

Comment: No Use. Still The Same Error

Comment: You may gain success with either: Val(Nz((Material_Require_Master.RMA_No)) = Other.RMA_no; ... or: Nz(Material_Require_Master.RMA_No) = Str(Other.RMA_no);  ... If so, try omitting the Nz, it may not be needed.